# checked="checked" not rendering as checked radio button in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

If I insert some html via js after the doc.ready than checked='checked' radio button doesn't render as checked in Google Chrome

also, I noticed that if I remove the name attribute from the input than it works

here is the whole thing:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.js"
type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function(){
$('body').append('<input type="radio" checked="checked" value="33" name="whatever" id="aeHobby0">');

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would appear to be a bug in 1.4.4 ([live copy](http://jsbin.com/ederup)). It works fine in 1.6.2 ([live copy](http://jsbin.com/ekugop)). Looks like it was fixed between 1.5.2 and 1.6.0 (at least in my tests), which suggests it was probably fixed by the patch that fixed bugs [8060](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8060) and [8500](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8500).

Comment: @Justin: [1.6.0 seems to work](http://jsbin.com/ekugop/4). But there are *other* [very good reasons](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/12/jquery-1-6-1-released/) to stay away from 1.6.0. ;-)

Comment: Help? I'm running chrome 21.0.1180.75 m the very latest as of 8/13/2012 and the problem seems to have returned. Any suggestions for a workaround?

Comment: @stu: I'm running the same version of Chrome. Oddly, *both* the links in the answer work correctly for me, as does trying it with jQuery 1.7.2. Might be a different problem entirely.

Comment: Turns out it was http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11937715/chrome-21-not-checking-radio-buttons